# Can CA SDI be added to state and local income taxes on 1040 NR Schedule A?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, california

Can I add CA SDI to State and Local Income taxes on 1040 NR Schedule A? I understand a NRA has to file 1040 NR and has to itemize the deductions.

I know that CA SDI can be added to State and local income taxes on Schedule A (1040), but it is not clearly mentioned that the same can be done on Schedule A 1040NR as well.

Any clarification will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Disability_Insurance) (and my personal understanding) - **yes**, you can.

> Employee contributions to the state fund are deductible as state
>   taxes.

IRS piece on this is [pub 17](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p17/ch22.html#d0e50062).

> Contributions to state benefit funds.    As an employee, you can
>   deduct mandatory contributions to state benefit funds withheld from
>   your wages that provide protection against loss of wages. For example,
>   certain states require employees to make contributions to state funds
>   providing disability or unemployment insurance benefits. Mandatory
>   payments made to the following state benefit funds are deductible as
>   state income taxes on Schedule A (Form 1040), line 5.
>
> Alaska Unemployment Compensation Fund.
>
> *California Nonoccupational Disability Benefit Fund*.
>
> New Jersey Nonoccupational Disability Benefit Fund.
>
> New Jersey Unemployment Compensation Fund.
>
> New York Nonoccupational Disability Benefit Fund.
>
> Pennsylvania Unemployment Compensation Fund.
>
> Rhode Island Temporary Disability Benefit Fund.
>
> Washington State Supplemental Workmen's Compensation Fund.

Note that while CA SDI is deductible - [VDI is not](http://littleadvisor.com/blog/archives/1083).

Comment: Actually you can do that for 1040 Sch A. But I am doubtful whether it can be done for 1040 NR ( notice NR) Sch A. 1040 NR is for non resident aliens. 1040 is for residents.

Comment: @abc - that's the only thing more or less that you **can** do. On NR you can (almost) only deduct state taxes, while residents can deduct tons of things.

Comment: @littleadv: Would I be able to add the SDI to my CA State tax if I were to take the standard deduction?